# xml onClicks no longer work for activity in android lollipop

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-activity, onclick, upgrade

The company I work for has an app which I've been working on for a while and been running on Android 4.4 perfectly fine. After one of our Nexus 5 got the lollipop update, suddenly all onClicks no longer work. I've tried running our app on other devices and in a vm and the same issue occurs. I can only show so much for proprietary code reasons but that shouldn't be an issue.

The first Activity with an onClick is the LoginActivity which extends Activity and doesn't touch fragments or dialogs (which are what all other results with similar problems cited as the problem). The example below is from a button that is supposed to let you choose your server:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{
...
    public void btnLoginServer_clicked(View v){
        Intent serversIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ServersActivity.class);
        startActivity(serversIntent);
    }
...
}
```

The stack trace says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.app, PID: 2241
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnLoginServer_clicked(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnLoginServer'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: btnLoginServer_clicked [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3987)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

And for good measure here's the xml of the button.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnLoginServerNoServer"
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginServer"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#de1bd500"
        android:onClick="btnLoginServer_clicked"
        android:background="@drawable/app_button_server_background" />
```

For a little extra clarification, the app was installed on two devices with android 4.4, they were upgraded to 5.0 and this problem began occurring. The app was removed and reinstalled, same problem. The app has been freshly installed on three other devices that had 5.0 but never had the app before, same problem. Same thing with a few different VMs.

Please help me. I don't have much hair left to pull out and I'm concerned I may throw something expensive at a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand entirely why this was the solution, maybe someone can explain.

There was a custom theme made for the app and it was applied to the app in the manifest. It was also applied to each of the activity layout xml files as android:theme="customTheme". Removing these from the layouts fixed the issue.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Its just google play services issue and nothing to do with your coding or settings blah blah...

just update your google play services of phone and add dependencies in build.gradle file like:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

and every thing or button will work.